# Using base class constructor in derived class contructor

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, c++14

Let's say that I want to make use of base class constructor in order to create derived class objects.

This is my approach on how to do it:

```cpp
class base
{
    int x, y, z;
public:
    base(int x, int y, int z)
        :
        x(x),
        y(y),
        z(z)
    {
        std::cout << "base class constructor called\n";
    }
    int get_x() const { return x; }
    int get_y() const { return y; }
    int get_z() const { return z; }
};

class derived : public base
{
    int value;
public:
    derived(int x, int y, int z, int value)
        :
        base(x, y, z),
        value(value)
    {
        std::cout << "derived class constructor called\n";
    };
    int get_val() const { return value; }  ;
    
};
```

My question: Is this the correct way of solving that problem? Or, is there some better approach on how to use base class constructor in derived class constructor?

Comment: The shown code looks fine.

Comment: Constructor such as `derived(base b, int value)` might make sense.

Comment: Yes this is the standard way of creating a derived object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an appropriate base class constructor 'call' in the initialization list for your derived class constructor is perfectly acceptable and normal. *(In fact, for the example that you've shown, **omitting** that constructor from the initialization list will cause the code to be ill-formed: the compiler will then attempt to default-construct the the `base` object and, since you have specified an explicit, argument-taking constructor, the default constructor for your `base` class is deleted.)*

One thing to note, however, is that that base class constructor will be executed *first*, even if you rearrange the specification order in that initialization list.

Take the slightly modified code below:

```cpp
class derived : public base {
    int value;
public:
    derived(int x_, int y_, int z_, int value_) // IMHO, using argument names same as members not good
        :
        value(value_),      // Rearrange list to have this appear first ...
        base(x_, y_, z_)    // ...but this is STILL called before the above
    {
        std::cout << "derived class constructor called\n";
    } // Note: Unnecessary semicolon after function (as also after getter).
    int get_val() const { return value; } // ; unnecessary
};
```

For this code, clang-cl gives this:

> warning : field 'value' will be initialized after base 'base'
> [-Wreorder-ctor]

And MSVC gives:

> warning C5038: data member 'derived::value' will be initialized after
> base class 'base'